# How to formalize "a group of prime rank is cyclic" in first order language?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Given group theory axioms

1. $\forall x\forall y\forall z,~x(yz)=(xy)z$
2. $\forall x,ex=xe=x$
3. $\forall x\exists y, xy=yx=e$

How to formalize the theorem that "a group of prime rank is cyclic"? Since "$|G|$ is a prime" is a predicate that refers to the domain of a model itself, how can we formalize it within this first order theory?

Comment: To make the question clearer : you're trying to find first order formulas $\phi$, $\psi$ such that $G\models \phi$ (resp. $\psi$) iff $G$ is of prime order (resp. $G$ is cyclic) and see that $T\vdash \phi\to\psi$ where $T$ is the theory of groups ?

Comment: @Max Yes, I think I want something like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer to the clearer version I gave in the comments. If that's not what you want then you can tell me.

For the rest of this answer, we consider theories over the language $L=\{\cdot, e\}$ (or $\{\cdot, e ,^{-1}\}$ would work as well)

There cannot be a theory $T$ such that if $G$ is a group, then $G$ is finite of prime order iff $G\models T$.

Indeed, there are infinitely many primes so the compactness theorem implies there is no such theory $T$ (by the usual theorem "If a theory $T$ has arbitrarily large finite models, then it has models of arbitrarily large (possibly infinite) cardinality")

Similarly, by the usual trick of adding constants (see for instance the beginning of a proof of the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem), and by noting that a cyclic group is at most countable, there is no first order theory $\Sigma$ in $L$ such that $G\models \Sigma$ iff $G$ is cyclic.

Therefore, the theorem "A group of prime order is cyclic" cannot be stated in the form "If $G\models T$ then $G\models \Sigma$", or  a fortiori in the form "$\mathbf{Grp} \vdash \phi \to \psi$" where $\mathbf{Grp}$  is the theory of groups in $L$.